# Remote database not empty

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to push my local database to Heroku using the following command:

```
heroku pg:push <local db name> DATABASE --app <heroku appname>
```

and I get:

> env: psql: No such file or directory  !    Remote database is not
>   empty.  !    Please create a new database, or use `heroku pg:reset`

So I run `heroku pg:reset` which resets it but I then get the following when trying to push again therefore going around in circles:

> env: psql: No such file or directory  !    Remote database is not
>   empty.  !    Please create a new database, or use `heroku pg:reset`

Any ideas on how to solve this?